# Console Application with Timers and the Skype API

Tags: vb.net, timer, console, skype4com

so i have a problem, when trying to call the Skype API on a timer it gets nothing, im just trying to read messages on a loop and display them in my console, but on timer tick, nothing happens. But if i put the timer tick code in main it works fine. Here is my code:

```
Imports SKYPE4COMLib
Imports System.Timers.Timer

Module main

Dim oSkype As New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype
Dim aUser = oSkype.User("echo123")
Dim aChat = oSkype.Messages(aUser.Handle)

Dim tmr As New Timers.Timer

Sub Main()

    tmr.AutoReset = True
    tmr.Interval = 1000
    AddHandler tmr.Elapsed, AddressOf tmrTick
    tmr.Enabled = True
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Public Sub tmrTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)

        For Each aMessages In aChat
            Console.WriteLine(aMessages.FromHandle & ": " & aMessages.Body)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("")

End Sub
End Module
```

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

Timers swallow exceptions, you might be getting an exception in the timer code, most likely a cross thread exception. Try settings visual studio to break on exceptions (debug > exceptions) and see if you get anything.

If you do get a cross thread exception, you wont be able to use System.timer timers as they run on the thread pool. in that case you should use a ui friendly timer such as the ones from winforms/wpf, or a dedicated thread

Comment: I get no exceptions or anything. And there is no "Exceptions" in debug.

Comment: Yes there is, under the debug menu in visual studio, there is a exceptions menu option where you can enable breaking on thrown exceptions, and what exceptions to break on.

Comment: im using Visual Basic 2010 Express and under the Debug menu there is nothing about exceptions and ive also used a try statement with a catch to see if it gets any type of errors and it doesnt.